# What language version should I refer to when answering a question?

Tags: discussion

When writing code in my answer, what language version should I use if one is not specified in the question? I always tend to use old versions syntax, if the latest version is still compatible with it. At the same time I surely would like to use some syntax sugar from newer versions, but I'm afraid of comments like "I've got a syntax error" which leads to more questions and mess in the comments.

Is there any tip for this?

Comment: You use the version you want to use to answer the question and then just mention the version number if necessary. When someone comments that they got a syntax error due to using a newer/older version isn't really your problem. You don't need to reply to them.

Comment: I, personally, *assume* that with lack of evidence to the contrary the user is using a fully supported version of the language that they have asked about, as it would seem *sensible* that a *responsible* person would ensure they are using supported software, or make people aware if they aren't. (We all know this isn't true.) Though I will often denote in an answer that the person must be using a fully supported version of said software. Then if they state it doesn't work due to being an old version, it's their lack of clarity that was the issue, not the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use syntax or other features from newer versions of the language.

That said, it doesn't hurt to be explicit about which newer syntax or feature your solution depends on, especially for very recent versions which many people will not have upgraded to yet. In that case your answer may also be improved by writing an alternative for people using an older version of the language. I wouldn't recommend writing *only* for an older language version just because the newer version is new; it won't be new for long, and your answer is meant to stay useful in the future (that's Stack Overflow's whole purpose).

For an example where specifying the version is actually necessary, some people write [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) answers which take advantage of dictionaries having insertion order, which has been guaranteed since Python 3.7. In these answers, it is actually necessary to explain that the solution only works for 3.7+, since the code will run without errors on older versions, just with incorrect results (due to dictionaries having different, implementation-dependent iteration orders in older versions).